# How to force VS to use appSettings value instead of My.Settings for WebService Reference

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, web-services, web-config

In visual studio 2008 when you add a web service reference, and set the Url behavior to dynamic it will create a My.Settings.Namespace.Webservice setting in a special My.Settings section in the web.config i do not like this style, i want to keep using the appSettings>value for this. how can i tell visual studio to use appSettings instead of My.Settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it to static, remove the My.Settings stuff you don't want, and load it from the appSettings section in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can tell VS to do the right thing. But you can tell the generated client object to use a different URL by setting the URL property of the client object.